# Combinations - Course choosing

Tags: combinations

Someone asked me this question:

> Suppose there are $n$ students. Each student must choose 4 courses, and
>   every two students can only have a maximum of one common course. How
>   many courses are needed to satisfy this condition?

I tried to convert this into a graph theory problem but failed to figure it out.

Comment: 2n${}{}{}{}{}{{}}$

Comment: @Awesome if $n=2$, you need $7$ courses...

Comment: @Foga I always make silly mistakes...

Comment: I get a bizarre pattern, which I am not 1-- percent sure is correct. Starting with $n=1$, my pattern is $4,7,8,10,10,11,12$

Comment: @mathguy I get something different, I get $4,7,9,10,10,11,12$. I don't see how to do it with $8$ in the third step.

Comment: @G.Bach I meant to say 9. Sorry about that. Thanks!

Comment: $x_1=4, x_{n+1} = x_n + n\mod 4$?

Comment: @baudolino That fails at $n+1=2$ whether we read it as $(x_n+n)\mod 4$ or as $x_n+(n\mod4)$.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that what is wanted is the **minimum** number of courses needed.

For $n=1\;thru\; 4,$ the pattern is $4,7,9,10$. The pattern for $n=5$ is shown below:

$\boxed{1,2}\;\boxed{1,3}\;\boxed{1,4}\;\boxed{1,5}\;\boxed{2,3}\;\boxed{2,4}\;\boxed{2,5}\;\boxed{3,4}\;\boxed{3,5}\;\boxed{4,5}\;$ and it repeats in cycles of $5$

Let number of courses needed for $(n\;mod\; 5)\;be\; k_i,\; i = 1\; thru\; 4$

Then minimum number of courses needed for $n$ students = $10\times \left[int\left(\dfrac{n}{5}\right)\right] + k_i$